# Forecasting future with Arima in Python (Key Error)

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, forecasting, arima

Im trying to use predict() from statsmodels' Arima library, to make future predictions based on my arima model. 
I have date as my timeseries index (which i converted using pd.datetime)

```
model = ARIMA(ts_log, order = (5, 1 ,2))
results_arima = model.fit(disp = -1)
pred1 = results_arima.predict(start = '2017-12-29' , end = '2018-01-29')
```

My timeseries ends at '2017-12-29' but I want to predict for a month ahead, as shown in the code.

This is the error that I get:
 **KeyError: "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2017-12-29'"**

This is what my timeseries looks like:

[image]

Comment: Your time/index colum seems to be a datetime-type. I'd suggest to pass a datetime object to the start and end parameters, f.e. datetime.datetime(2017,12,29,0,0,0) etc.

Comment: @dorvak Hey, doing this gives me the following error
__TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'__

Comment: Could you post some data/code to reproduce your example?